# On which side of creepage gap should I put my optocoupler?

Tags: power-supply, pcb, pcb-design, opto-isolator

I'm designing a flyback power supply and I need to use an optocoupler for zero-crossing detection. The reference design I was given put the optocoupler on the MCU/low voltage side and I find that to be problematic.

I believe you should group them together with high voltage components on one side of creepage gap? I could be wrong, and I hope to get some input from experts and experienced engineers, thanks.

I have already searched and no one had asked this specific question or anything close.

Edit: by "creepage gap" I actually was referring loosely to creepage clearance and air gap, the deliberate blank area on PCB boards to separate high and low voltage components.

Comment: In you terminology is "creepage gap" synonymous to "isolation barrier" ?  A sketch could help make this question clearer.

Comment: Um, actually I was referring to the board cut-outs between high voltage components and low voltage components. https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4oGJ.jpg

Comment: The optocoupler should be straddling the gap (slot). Otherwise you compromise the entire purpose of the gap.

Answer (score 7):

Generally you will have a few critical components that straddle the gap between supply and output voltage- a feedback optocoupler, a Y safety rated capacitor, the 'transformer', and, in your case apparently, another opto.

If you are having the board maker mill slots to increase the creepage distance, the slot should go **under** the optoisolator. See, for example, [this](http://int03.co.uk/blog/2015/02/) PCB layout:

[image]

If that means putting the optocoupler "backwards" with respect to other chips on the board, that's just too bad.

Answer (score 3):

Generally the whole point of opto-coupler (also known as opto-isolator) is to put them at the boundary between the logic side and the high voltage side.

Further, if there is a split in the power planes or ground planes at that point they should straddle that.

From your definition of creepage slot, the opto-couplers should straddle the gap with the low side closest to the low voltage area.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, I think I know what you mean, I don't have to care about where to put them relative to air gaps, even on the same side as MCUs, but I do have to make sure the optocoupler straddles the ground polygon pour and the non-ground (high voltage polygon pour, if there is one at all) polygon pour (or a lack there off).

Comment: Yup, but you don't want to run your high voltage traces on the output of the opto-coupler over to the logic side either. (or vica-versa) Hence they should be at the crossover point.

Comment: No problemo! I had that in mind when doing the designing, the low V side to digital, high V side to power source.